# According to Catholic Tradition, did God the Father ever teach or punish God the Son?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-god, trinity, persons-of-the-trinity, god-the-father

Catholics are taught to believe in the Trinity - God in Three Persons - The Father, Son, and Holy Spirit.

If Catholics are taught to worship God "The Father" and God "The Son", then did "The Father" ever need to teach or punish God "The Son"?

Moreover: How does God "The Father" and God "The Son" continue to interact in present-day life? Should Catholics think of God "The Son" as an adult with an adult relationship with God "The Father"?

Comment: Are you excluding the learning that Jesus undertook as a human child?

Comment: Jesus most certainly learned as a child, but did the Bible detail how He interacted with God the Father? Perhaps the 40 days in the desert?

Comment: This question shows a lack of serious understanding as to what the Sacred Trinity truly entails whether of Catholic or other major denominations believe, such as the Orthodox or the Anglican Churches, which hold similar positions on this subject.

Comment: @Ken Graham: Can you please explain? How did I misunderstand the Holy Trinity?

Comment: That should be detailed in your question. This is an easy enough subject to find online. Can you link a source that believes Catholics ever taught or teach that  God the Father ever teach or punished God the Son?

Comment: @KenGraham Not necessarily: There are Catholic priests interpreting Hebrews 5:8 this way. And one priest interpreted Mt 15,26-27 in that way in a sermon: Jesus had to **learn** that all people are made by God; and the feeling he had after he was aware that he insulted a person as "dog" was surely some kind of punishment.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Then post an answer with appropriate links and sources.! **According to Catholic Tradition, did God the Father ever teach or punish God the Son?**

Comment: @KenGraham Unfortunately, I don't know if those priests' opinion reflects official teaching or only their personal opinion. And the question was about the official teaching.

Comment: At least as far as learning is concerned...Heb 5:8  Although he was a son, he learned obedience through what he suffered.

Comment: As far as punishment is concerned...Isaiah 53:5 upon him was the chastisement that brought us peace,

Comment: @KenGraham: `This is an easy enough subject to find online.` Huh? This is exactly why I asked the question! Can you please relax a bit?

Comment: **According to Catholic Tradition, did God the Father ever teach or punish God the Son?** In what sense? Through his human nature or his divine nature? This needs more clarity.

Comment: @Ken Graham: In either sense

Answer (score 1):

God the Father and God the Son have been of the same spirit since the beginning of time. (Nicene Creed: ... *begotten not made, consubstantial with the Father*).  Likewise, they will be until the end of time and all times.

They are not exactly the same, but are very much the same.  In the same kind of way a husband and wife become the same, or are unified in guiding their child to become themselves in spite of worldly influence. When God the Father gave the world His only begotten son, He did so that some would listen and believe and trade the ways of the world for perfection in Him through His son, to not ever "*perish, but have everlasting life*" (John 3:16).

Through God the Son, it is possible to be perfect as the Father in Heaven is perfect. *"Be you therefore perfect as your Father in Heaven is perfect," "No one comes to the Father except through me"* (Matthew 5:48, John 14:6).  A perfect parent will perfectly instruct a perfect child who will never require punishment.  Prior to His brutal treatment by a world who chose wickedness over perfection, the son of God looks to the Father and says, "*Father please, let this pass me by that I might not suffer this horrible agony and humiliation, but only if it is your will to intervene and allow me to escape it*" (Matthew 26:39). Neither the church nor the bible give much insight into the will of the Father here, or why he would allow something so horrible to happen. God the Son, as one with the Father, had earlier promised to "*rebuild the temple in three days*" (John 2:19) which also made good on a prophecy that still needed to be fulfilled.

I think it is safe to believe that the Son is never disobedient to the Father and therefore can never been a candidate for punishment.  I think it is also safe to believe that the father would have preferred that the world had been obedient from the beginning and not rejected Him or His son, but was willing to pay the ultimate price to save a few.